# Rewrite Contains() method C#

Tags: c#, string

I Have this clausule

```
if ((line.Contains('%')) || (line.Contains('@')) || (line.Contains("") && (!line.Contains(','))))
```

and i want rewrite it to one method,beacause this is too slow. Any ideas??

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: `line.Contains("")`!?

Comment: `line.Contains("")` will always return true. It says so even in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx).

Comment: Looked at RegExp or IndexOfAny() ?

Comment: Write a method that loops through each character in the string checking for `%`, `@` if the current character is either of these return true immediately. Also in your loop keep track of whether a `,` was encountered. If you get to the end of your loop and it wasn't then also return true, but if you reach the end and it was then return false.

Comment: `bool MyContains (string line) { return ((line.Contains('%')) || (line.Contains('@')) || (line.Contains("") && (!line.Contains(',')))); }`

As you can see, just because code is encapsulated into a single method, it doesn't mean it will be any faster.

Comment: How fast should it be? Also: put the 'Contains' in order from left to right from most likely to be true to least likely to be true.

Comment: *slow* ? seriously ? .. does the number of words in `line` fits in a [Decimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.maxvalue.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both the other answers seem to ignore the fact that the original code returns true when `line` contains `%` or `@` or when it does **NOT** contain `,`. (the empty string being totally irrelevant).

The correct way to write this would be:

```
if(line.Intersect("%@").Any() || !line.Contains(","))
```

Or possibly:

```
char[] includes = { '%', '@' };
char[] excludes = { ',' };
if(line.Intersect(includes).Any() || !line.Intersect(excludes).Any())
```

Or this:

```
char[] includes = { '%', '@' };
char[] excludes = { ',' };
if(line.IndexOfAny(includes) != -1 || line.IndexOfAny(excludes) == -1)
```

Answer (score 9):

```
if(line.Intersect("%@,").Any())
```

or

```
if("%@,".Intersect(line).Any())
```

(Reversing the parameters may improve performance, depending on the type of data in `line` and the percentage of characters that match.)

Comment: I just tried to post exactly this, but SO apparently detects people with faster fingers now! +1

Comment: Not sure that would be faster than what he has. (Though i'd agree it probably doesn't need to be). Unless he means faster to type.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett It would be a lot faster in the case that it doesn't actually match the first character checked.  If the `%` would match a character this will be slower.

Comment: Can you extend it to handle the `line.Contains("")` case?

Comment: @Geoff `line.Contains("")` does nothing, it just returns TRUE.  Anything ANDed with TRUE is itself, so that part of the code is an expensive noop.

Comment: @Servy: That's interesting. Not sure what Intersect does in the background, but my intuition (has been known to be wrong!) says it's slower or around the same.

Comment: Yep, was kidding - sorry

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Then perhaps you should go figure out what `Intersect` does in the background before commenting on it's performance.

Comment: @Geoff Oh, that's fine.  It seems [a few others](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16151450/1159478) think that it does something other than nothing.

Comment: @Servy: Point taken. I did say "not sure" for that reason though. :) Also, note that the logic for the comma isn't the same as the % and @

Comment: @spender Actually, they are all `||`.  The only AND is with `line.Contains("")`, which is always true.  Anything anded with true is itself, and after that all that's left is a series of OR operations.

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Except that it is.  See previous comment.

Comment: @Servy : yes, I realised and deleted my comment

Comment: +1 i had same thoughts but you had it already written... :(

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett As to the performance of intersect, see [this article](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/30/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-16-intersect-and-build-fiddling.aspx).  In short, it will throw all of the search strings into a hashset, then go through each char in `line` to determine if it's in that set.  Depending on the expected contents of `line` and the expected match rate, it may improve performance to flip the parameters.

Comment: Thanks for the link, much appreciated. Re. The comma unless I'm being dumb, surely the ! Would change the logic even with the contains being true.

Answer (score 1):

First, lets simplify the whole statement. You use to many hooks:

```
if (line.Contains('%') || line.Contains('@') || line.Contains("") && !line.Contains(','))
```

Second, as stated before, line.Contains("") will always return true. Perhapse you are missing a space or something.

Last, searching a string (or an array of characters) for the orrucance of a character is FAST! The whole search-operation is just one simple operation at assembly level (REP SCASW). In this case you have to search for more than once characters, which will result in one or more simple assembly instructions. Other statements in C# are perhapse shorter, but probably not faster.

Search for a string inside a string is slightly slower, so try to remove the Contains("").

Other operations (with LINQ or REGEX) will probably result into more: memory-operations (for arrays, delegates, result types), more analyzation (multiple characters inside an array of characters), etc. etc.